# mean calculation in pandas excluding zeros

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a direct way to calculate the mean of a dataframe column in pandas but not taking into account data that has zero as a value? Like a parameter inside the .mean() function?
Was currently doing it like this:

```
x = df[df[A]!=0]
x.mean()
```

Comment: Are you looking for `df[df[A]!=0].mean()`?

Comment: was wondering if something like df['A'].mean(exclude=0) or something like that existed. But I guess no advantage over this way.

Comment: The only thing you can exclude like that is NaN .

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It also depends on the meaning of 0 in your data.

- If these are indeed '0' values, then your approach is good
- If '0' is a placeholder for a value that was not measured (i.e. 'NaN'), then it might make more sense to replace all '0' occurrences
  with 'NaN' first. Calculation of the mean then by default exclude NaN
  values.

  ```
  df = pd.DataFrame([1, 0, 2, 3, 0], columns=['a'])
  df = df.replace(0, np.NaN)
  df.mean()
  ```

Comment: You can take advantage of the fact that `df.replace()` creates a new series and doesn't operate inplace:

`df.loc["Means", "myCol"] = df["myCol"].replace(0, np.nan).mean(skipna=True)`

This is what I use to calculate a non-zero mean and place it at the end of the column without impacting my existing df values (since I want them to stay as 0 not nan)

Answer (score 2):

```
df[df["Column_name"] != 0]["Column_name"].mean()
```

or if your column name does not contain space char

```
df[df.Column_Name != 0].Column_Name.mean()
```

hopefully it can be included as a parameter in the next "mean" object version

```
.mean(exclude=0)  #wondering in next versions
```

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the discussion, but you can also do:

```
df[df["Column_name"] != 0].mean()
```

Comment: (corrected the posted code - though it is just a duplicate still)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert df to numpy array and use [numpy.nanmean()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html:)

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([[1, 2], 
                                 [3, 4], 
                                 [6, 7], 
                                 [8, np.nan], 
                                 [np.nan, 11]]), 
                  columns=['A', 'B'])

df_col_means = numpy.nanmean(df.values)  # by columns
df_row_means = numpy.nanmean(df.values, axis=1)  # by rows
col_A_mean = numpy.nanmean(df['A'].values)  # particular column mean
```